# Add an integer value to a floating point value in Gforth

Tags: forth, gforth

In [Gforth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gforth), is there a way to add an integer value to a floating point value?

Something like `1 + 2.1`? If I do `1 2.1e f+` I get an error which I'm guessing is because the values are not on the same stack. I know that I could just do `1.0e 2.1e f+`, but that's not what I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gforth has the `s>f` and `d>f` words that convert an int (single cell and double cell respectively) to a double - Gforth floating point functions doc is [here](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Floating-Point.html)

```
1 s>f 2.1e f+
```

should do the trick in this case.

Comment: That didn't quite work so I tried 1 s>f 2.1e f+ and got the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @user1981802 sorry for the confusion, looks like my Forth knowledge is getting quite rusty.  I changed by answer to mention both s>f and d>f